# How to place text centered over an image?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place some text over a button image. I manage to align it center from left to right on the button, but vertical alignment doesn't do the trick for the rest of it. Is there a way in the CSS in order to be able to center that text vertically.

[image]

```
.selectedTabOnPlacementMenu
{
    background: url('/Content/Images/Blank_Yellow.png') no-repeat;
    width:88px;
    height:28px;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: It would help if you provided your css and html.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is a single line of text, you can set line-height.

```
<div style="height:50px;background-color:#ccc;">
    <p style="line-height:50px;">test</p>
</div>
```

It is much more difficult to vertically center multiple lines of text.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the code

```
line-height:28px;
```

in your class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use margin-top: 5px; or padding-top:5px; (depending on how your div is setup) in the div where you have your text to push it down.

Cheers